# VBA Write Data From Excel Cell to Text/Batch File

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, updates

I have an Excel File that stores a file path within Cell A1 and concatenates with the Function TODAY() to update that file path.

I also have a batch file that will move files from one folder to another.  I currently use this updating excel cell to get the new move batch command.

How can I use VBA to copy data from Sheet1 in Cell A1 to the batch file automatically?

Batch file is stored 
C:\Desktop\Batch\update.bat

Here is an example code from the comments below but I just want it to copy data from Sheet 1 and Cell A1

```
Dim FilePath As String
Dim CellData As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

FilePath = "C:\Batch\copy.bat"

Open FilePath For Output As #2

For i = 1 To LastRow

    For j = 1 To LastCol

        If j = LastCol Then

            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)

        Else

            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + ","

        End If

    Next j

    Write #2, CellData
    CellData = ""

Next i

Close #2

MsgBox ("Done")
```

Comment: Did you even search for how to do it? it's very common and all over the net. [Here's one example](http://www.homeandlearn.org/write_to_a_text_file.html) (a bit more than you need, but has the elements)

Comment: I just want a single cell not a range.  Many of the ones on the internet are a range and I new to VBA

Comment: a single cell is Range as well. `Range("A1")`

Comment: So in your example how would you edit the following to just reference sheet1 and cell A1

Comment: replace the entire `For ... Next` loop with `Write #2, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman that worked, thank you! One more question if you dont mind when it writes to the text file I get " " marks.  Is there any way to get rid of those?

Comment: there is, but I forgot how, you can search and find the anser

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  I had to use Print instead of Write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim FilePath As String
Dim CellData As String

FilePath = "C:\Batch\copy.bat"

Open FilePath For Output As #2

r = Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text

Print #2 r
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.