# How do I write a Visual Basic Application (Excel) program that writes text from two cells into a new text file?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I write a Visual Basic Application (Excel) program that writes text from two cells into a new text file when I click a button? I know very little, if anything at all, about Visual Basic, much less about Visual Basic Application.
All of the online resources have failed me as either they don't work the way I intend the program to or don't work at all, giving me errors I have no idea how to solve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105691/vba-write-data-from-excel-cell-to-text-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\text_file.txt"
    Set rng = Selection
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    cellValue = Range("A1").Value
    Write #1, cellValue
    cellValue = Range("B1").Value
    Write #1, cellValue
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I stop it from overwriting the previous data and just add it in a new line?

Comment: In line Open myFile For Output As #1 change Output to Append

Comment: Thanks, I think I can figure out the other issues myself

Comment: Great, so you can mark this answer as right? The place, where the txt is saved is defined in \text_file.txt. You can use \path\to\folder\text_file.txt

Comment: Thanks :-). Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

This Macro do it. Just select, which cells you want to write in file and run it.

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\text_file.txt"
    Set rng = Selection
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
            If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
                Write #1, cellValue
            Else
                Write #1, cellValue,
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Close #1
End Sub
```

File text_file.txt is saved in place, where is saved Excel file.

Comment: Is there any way i can do it on two fixed cells instead of having to select them every time?

Comment: Also, the file is not saved in the same place as the excel file, but that's a minor issue.